# Regular 401 & 405 errors from apache webdav server

Tags: apache, http, webdav

I keep getting these 401 and 405 errors in my apache webdav server log, and I can't figure out what's causing them.

```
192.168.1.2 - - [11/Feb/2023:10:32:11 +0100] "PROPFIND /dt/dt_nginx.dtCloud/ HTTP/1.0" 401 381
192.168.1.2 - dt [11/Feb/2023:10:32:11 +0100] "PROPFIND /dt/dt_nginx.dtCloud/ HTTP/1.0" 207 323
192.168.1.2 - dt [11/Feb/2023:10:32:11 +0100] "GET /dt/dt_nginx.dtCloud/inbox/master.plist HTTP/1.0" 200 224
192.168.1.2 - dt [11/Feb/2023:10:32:11 +0100] "PROPFIND /dt/dt_nginx.dtCloud/inbox/ HTTP/1.0" 207 1830
192.168.1.2 - - [11/Feb/2023:10:32:12 +0100] "PROPFIND /dt/dt_nginx.dtCloud/ HTTP/1.0" 401 381
192.168.1.2 - dt [11/Feb/2023:10:32:13 +0100] "PROPFIND /dt/dt_nginx.dtCloud/ HTTP/1.0" 207 323
192.168.1.2 - dt [11/Feb/2023:10:32:13 +0100] "GET /dt/dt_nginx.dtCloud/7b8b717fa62fddda7fe843879f442edee1fba942ff339ba131e4f01d752316f5/master.plist HTTP/1.0" 200 224
192.168.1.2 - dt [11/Feb/2023:10:32:13 +0100] "PROPFIND /dt/dt_nginx.dtCloud/7b8b717fa62fddda7fe843879f442edee1fba942ff339ba131e4f01d752316f5/ HTTP/1.0" 207 2243
192.168.1.2 - - [11/Feb/2023:10:32:35 +0100] "PROPFIND /dt/dt_nginx.dtCloud/ HTTP/1.0" 401 381
192.168.1.2 - dt [11/Feb/2023:10:32:35 +0100] "PROPFIND /dt/dt_nginx.dtCloud/ HTTP/1.0" 207 323
192.168.1.2 - dt [11/Feb/2023:10:32:35 +0100] "GET /dt/dt_nginx.dtCloud/53cbd346392b8673a03715b8c62f03559f470c38c6c79289f273814a7023841f/master.plist HTTP/1.0" 200 224
192.168.1.2 - dt [11/Feb/2023:10:32:35 +0100] "PROPFIND /dt/dt_nginx.dtCloud/53cbd346392b8673a03715b8c62f03559f470c38c6c79289f273814a7023841f/ HTTP/1.0" 207 2244
192.168.1.2 - dt [11/Feb/2023:10:32:35 +0100] "MKCOL /dt/dt_nginx.dtCloud/ HTTP/1.0" 405 222
192.168.1.2 - dt [11/Feb/2023:10:32:35 +0100] "PROPFIND /dt/dt_nginx.dtCloud/ HTTP/1.0" 207 323
192.168.1.2 - dt [11/Feb/2023:10:32:35 +0100] "MKCOL /dt/dt_nginx.dtCloud/53cbd346392b8673a03715b8c62f03559f470c38c6c79289f273814a7023841f/ HTTP/1.0" 405 222
192.168.1.2 - dt [11/Feb/2023:10:32:35 +0100] "PROPFIND /dt/dt_nginx.dtCloud/53cbd346392b8673a03715b8c62f03559f470c38c6c79289f273814a7023841f/ HTTP/1.0" 207 388
192.168.1.2 - dt [11/Feb/2023:10:32:35 +0100] "MKCOL /dt/dt_nginx.dtCloud/53cbd346392b8673a03715b8c62f03559f470c38c6c79289f273814a7023841f/receipts/ HTTP/1.0" 405 222
192.168.1.2 - dt [11/Feb/2023:10:32:35 +0100] "PROPFIND /dt/dt_nginx.dtCloud/53cbd346392b8673a03715b8c62f03559f470c38c6c79289f273814a7023841f/receipts/ HTTP/1.0" 207 397
```

The relevant `httpd.conf` section has:

```
Listen 21028

LoadModule dav_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule dav_fs_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_dav_fs.so
LoadModule dav_lock_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_dav_lock.so

DavLockDB /usr/local/etc/httpd/webdavdb/davlock

<VirtualHost 192.168.1.2:21028>
    ServerName my.server.me
    ServerAlias my.server.me
    DocumentRoot /Volumes/E/apache/webdav
    <Directory /Volumes/E/apache/webdav>
        Dav On
        AuthType Digest
        AuthName "webdav"
        AuthUserFile /usr/local/etc/httpd/webdavdb/users.password
        Require valid-user
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This was working fine for several weeks but for some reason I can't figure out — non modification to confs or anything relevant on the machine - the server keeps spitting these errors.

EDIT: For testing, I've removed the `Require valid-user` directive and this "fixes" the `401` problem (for the moment). However, I am still getting `405` for any request with the `MKCOL` method (see log above).

The Apache DAV server is behind an nginx reverse proxy. I am *not* getting these errors when connecting to the apache server directly via a local address (192.168.1.2) and `http`. It seems the problem is somewhere in the way nginx forwards the requests to apache, but I don't know what can be the problem with my `nginx.conf`:

```
server {
    server_name my.server.me;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2:12345;
    }

    location /robots.txt {
        return 200 "User-agent: *\nDisallow: /\n";
    }

    proxy_set_header Host              $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    # SSL stuff
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

401 is not really an error but uthentificatiob prompt. When a browser or other http/webdav client see the 401 status code it will ask a user for credentials and then send them in header Authorization: Basic user:pass.
So when you disabled authorization the problem was "solved". Turn the authorization back!

The 405 error means that a server doesn't allow to make the operation (http method). In your case it rejected MKCOL request i.e. an attempt to create a folder.
This is probably because you disabled auth and the server doesn't allow editing.
Also note that you may have auth in both nginx proxy and apache webdav.